# After using push(), array is logged as a number

Tags: javascript, arrays, push

I'm trying to get an array of some images to flip through. The first set need to be in descending order, while the second set need to be in ascending order, so I have written this:

```
var flipArray = [];

function createFlipArray(older, newer){

    flipArray = $("#"+older).children();

    flipArray = flipArray.get().reverse();

    flipArray = flipArray.push($('#'+newer).children());

    console.log(flipArray);


    loopThroughImages();

}
```

When I push the second set onto the first set, it logs the array as 4, even though there are 6 items in the whole array.

If I log the array after I populate it with the older children, it returns with HTML objects, which I expect to see after I push the newer children on.

Any suggestions?

Comment: If it's "logged as", then suspect that it is - come up with some hypothesis and test them. The console works well for this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Array.prototype.push` returns the array's new length. It *modifies* the original array. Remove the `flipArray =` before it.

Answer (score 6):

[`.push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) modifies the array in-place.  It does *not* return a new array, it returns the array's new length.