# Why can't direcrlty return a value by using .push() in javascript?

Tags: javascript, callback

using below flatten function as example, why cant I use `return` directly on the accumulator. Push()

```
 function flatten(array){
      return reduce(array,function(accumulator, value){
          if(Array.isArray(value)){
              each(value,function(value1){    
                  return accumulator.push(value1);     //as shown 
                  })
              }else{
                  return accumulator.push(value);      //as shown
                  }  

          },[]); 
      };
```

Instead, I need to return accumulator on a separate line?

```
 function flatten(array){
      return reduce(array,function(accumulator, value){
          if(Array.isArray(value)){
              each(value,function(value1){
                  accumulator.push(value1);
                  })
              }else{
                  accumulator.push(value);   
                  }  
            return accumulator             //as shown 
          },[]);  
      };
```

but if use method such as .concat() I will be able to use `return` on it...

Comment: Because `push` returns a number but `concat` returns a new array?

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_push.asp

Comment: You might want to have a look at [this old answer of mine about the `Array` API design](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13349715/1048572)

Comment: Just read the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push).

Comment: @brso05: Please link MDN (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push), [not w3schools](http://www.w3fools.com/)

Comment: @Bergi no I'll probably just link either one...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [After using push(), array is logged as a number](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15165288/after-using-push-array-is-logged-as-a-number)

Comment: @brso05: Yes, and MDN is objectively the better one…

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `push` method returns the new length of the Array.

[MDN documentation for push](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push)

The `concat` method returns a brand new array containing a combination of the two arrays.

[MDN documentation for concat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat)

Answer (score 0):

If you want a somewhat 'odd' solution that will mean you can return on the same line, you could do this:
`return (accumulator.push(value1) + 1) && accumulator;`

The +1 is to ensure an index of 0 is turned true.

Like I sad, it allows you to return on the line you want, but with odd code. Might suit you case maybe?

But it seems what you'd want to use is `concat`