# Why does the code return the number of iterations that executed over the actual value?

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

I'm studying Javascript, I came across a typical basic for loop that was structured like this:

```
var myArry = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i += 2){
    console.log(myArry);
}
```

This I understand, it will return the array as a whole with the values of i specified in the counter.

However I then pasted the following code out of curiosity. To see if i'd get the same result, which was what I assumed bring. However what I got was how many iterations happened before the loop ended?

````
```console.log(myArry.push(i));```
````

I know this is trivial, but I just want to understand how the language interprets the above line as the amount of times the for loop iterated before it ends.

Is the above line of code showing how many times push is executed, or is it some other abstraction I'm missing?

Any clarification is greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_push.asp `Array.push()` returns the size of the array after the push. It adds to the array. So what you're looking for is `myArray.push(i); console.log(myArray);`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [After using push(), array is logged as a number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15165288/after-using-push-array-is-logged-as-a-number)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Array.push returns the number of items in the array after that push is completed. it returns the equivalent of Array.length().

See ref hre
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push